# update and select in one SQL query

Tags: sql

I wrote a query that updates a field in a table but I wish to add an additional parameter - the name of the student (that inside a different table - "Students")

This is what I wrote till now (just an example):

```
UPDATE Grades
SET FinalExam = 90
FROM Grades AS grd
INNER JOIN Students
ON grd.Exam_ID = Students.Exam_ID
WHERE grd.BOUNUS = 1
```

How can I add a select method in this query to return me the Students name?

Comment: `SET FinalExam = 90, Name=Students.Name` ?

Comment: Instead of "2 Rows Updates" I want to return the students name that will get the 90 grade

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need an additional select, since you are already joining to the students table, assuming 'Name' is a column in the Students table:

```sql
UPDATE Grades
SET FinalExam = 90, `Name`=stud.Name
FROM Grades AS grd
INNER JOIN Students AS stud
ON grd.Exam_ID = stud.Exam_ID
WHERE grd.BOUNUS = 1;
```

But note that the column name 'Name' must be enclosed in backticks since it is an SQL reserved word.  if you named the column something else (and this assumes that it is an additional column with 'FinalExam' in the 'Grades' table), it may not require the backticks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    update Grades
SET FinalExam = 90
where grad.Exam_ID in ( select grd.Exam_ID from grade grd inner join Students.Exam_ID
having grd.BOUNUS=1
)
```